# Go to parent directory in System.Net.FtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm using `System.Net.FtpClient` to work with FTP server in my web application.
After creating a directory and set it as working directory and uploading files in it, I want to go back one step (the parent directory) to do the same for other folders and files, but I don't know how to get the parent and set it as working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use a relative path to enter the subdirectory like below.

```
ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory("subdir");
```

Were you using an absolute path, I assume you would know how to open the parent directory.

To enter a parent directory, use `".."`:

```
ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory("..");
```

See [Representations of paths by operating system and shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell) on Wikipedia.

You can always use the absolute path:

```
ftpClient.SetWorkingDirectory("/path/to/parent/directory");
```